# Pasting Extra Characters to Each element of a List Using Purrr Package R

Tags: r, functional-programming, purrr

I have a list I want to iterate over and add characters to the end of each word. However, depending on the element in the list I would like to change the word being added. I am also looking for some intuition behind the answer. Lastly, I am looking for an answer using functional programming from the purrr package.

```
#Here is the output without using purrr

my.list = list(first = c("AAPL", "MSFT"),
               second = c("AMZN", "NFLX"))

paste(my.list[["first"]][1], ".O")
paste(my.list[["first"]][2], ".O")
paste(my.list[["second"]][1], ".P")
paste(my.list[["second"]][2], ".P")
```

Desired Output would be a list that would like so.

```
$first
"AAPL.O" "MSFT.O"

$second
"AMZN.P" "NFLX.P"
```

The first vector in my list receives ".O" at the end of each word in the vector. 
The second vector in my list receives ".P" at the end of each word.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over 2 list/vector of the same size using `purrr::map2`. `paste0` works like `paste` but concatenates without spaces. `paste/paste0` is vectorized so something like `test <- letters[1:5]; paste0(test, "test")` works.

```
suffix <- c(".O", ".P")
purrr::map2(my.list, suffix, ~paste0(.x, .y))
```